# graph database revision control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, version-control, neo4j, graph-databases

GitHub for Neo4J?

I'm evaluating graph databases as a possible solution for modeling a complex computer network. It occurs to me something like a revision control system would be useful for planning and testing updates to the database. I had been assuming that either we would instantiate a test network graph for such planning and then write a routing to sync the changes.

I see that this question has been asked and answered for relational databases ([How do you maintain revision control of your database structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294758/how-do-you-maintain-revision-control-of-your-database-structure)). But I'm asking for graph databases, probably Neo4J.

In that relational thread someone pitches the Rails approach of making rollback a required element of database development. I like this idea too; I'm not sure how easy it is in graph databases.

How is this handled in the real world?

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while also searching for an answer, so I don't have tested solutions to offer. But I can share that there's some discussion of this at [How do I implement revisions with neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707538/how-do-i-implement-revisions-with-neo4j), including a specific case at [Neo4j / Strategy to keep history of node changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073512/neo4j-strategy-to-keep-history-of-node-changes).

There's also a more detailed blog post at http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/, which weighs the read-time / write-time / storage requirements of several alternatives. It also includes a number of diagrams and example queries that helped me wrap my head around what all this would look like.

Hope that's still useful, lo these months later, and sorry I can't be of more help! If you've found something that works in the meantime, can you let us know?

Comment: My experience with Neo4J (I have used the java API only) is that is doesn't handle the super nodes well.